# Changing CK editor filder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ckeditor

I created a asp.net web application and then I downloaded ckeditor. And I extracted my application directory this editor folder. And I added dll of ckeditor to reference of my application. I registered in my web page.

```
<add tagPrefix="CKEditor" assembly="CKEditor.NET" namespace="CKEditor.NET"/>
```

I can use ck editor as well. But when I put ckeditor to child folder, I didn't use ckeditor.

root
  MyDefault.aspx
  MyEditor
    ckeditor folder

I want to use like this. How could I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ckeditor in my website...

I set it rootforlder/js/ckeditor(folder)

I add below tag in page where I used ckeditor.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

I used ckeditor control like below...

```
 <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="ckService" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="400px" BasePath="~/js/ckeditor/"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

I hope this will help you... please, let me know.. if you want any help regarding it.